# git commit on Windows shared network folder

Tags: git, git-for-windows

I want to use a Hyper-V Windows Virtual Machine for development. In order to backup all my data I've "mounted" (mapped) a shared directory of the host OS into the virtual machine. I can edit files in this shared directory just fine.

However, git does not work properly. Whenever I try to commit something it tells me:

> fatal: cannot update the ref 'HEAD': unable to append to '.git/logs/HEAD': Invalid argument

What is the problem? Is this a known incompatibility?

`git status` seems to work just fine.

Comment: In contrast to other directories, I cannot delete the .git directory from within the VM. So it's probably some kind of access rights problem. I've executed `git init` from within the VM though. So I don't know what could have gone wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone runs into this, I've found a workaround. I've made the directory a local one in the VM and gave the host machine network access. So the host can reach it the other way round and I can backup the directory without the VM being backed up completely.

Answer (score 2):

I can't say whether it is a *known* incompatibility, but this:

> ```
> fatal: cannot update the ref 'HEAD':
> unable to append to '.git/logs/HEAD': Invalid argument
> ```

strongly suggests that the particular file system setup you're using simply does not support open-for-append:

```
*fd = open(path, O_APPEND | O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0666);
```

or:

```
*logfd = open(logfile, O_APPEND | O_WRONLY, 0666);
```

from C code.  Whichever of these two is being used—which one is used depends on whether the file `.git/logs/HEAD` already exists or not—the `open` system call is returning `EINVAL`.

As `O_WRONLY` and `O_CREAT` *are* supported in all file systems that allow any kind of file-writing at all, the problem has to lie with file system's implementation of the `O_APPEND` flag.

Comment: Why are you assuming it's a problem with appending?  Wouldn't this exact same error happen if the process simply doesn't have write access to the file?

Comment: @JoelFan: if `open` returns `EINVAL` for *all* writes, you can't write anything at all to any file, which would be quite noticeable. (The OP notes that editing files works.) Besides that, `O_APPEND` requires something that may be difficult to implement in some remote-file-system architectures. It's not a guarantee, it just seems highly probable.

Comment: Also, note that "not allowed" should return a permission-denied (`EACCES`) error, not an invalid-argument (`EINVAL`) error.

Comment: Hmm, thank you for your answer. I'm really thinking you're on the right track. Do you have an idea how to overcome the problem?

Comment: @DR : you could compile an exe, which tries to write to a file, and append to a file ; confirm that it works as expected (on your host machine, and possibly in the VM on the regular filesystem), and see how it behaves when targeting a file in that "mounted" filesystem.

Comment: If a test program behaves this way, and the C library `fopen` for `"a"` (append) mode works, find out what the C library is doing—possibly, open-and-seek-on-each-write. Or, try doing open-and-seek-on-each-write anyway (`lseek` to end of file). Unfortunately even if you do find something that works, you'll then have to build a new Git binary to make it use this, or come up with a way of intercepting the `open` system call. That all assumes that my guess here is right of course.